# Delphi multiple indexed generic list

Tags: delphi, generics

I am looking for a TList descendent which lets me add one or more indexes and lets me search and view by these indexes.

A 30min google search session has left me with nothing.

This must have been needed before. I mean how many times have you had a in memory indexed collection and then needed to display it in a different order?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: Have you looked at [delphi-coll](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-coll/) ? Lots of generic list types with different sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered [TClientDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/DBClient.TClientDataSet)? It can be sorted and filtered at runtime. An article can be found at http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29056

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a generic implementation of a [Multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) in Delphi, [LU RD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576719/lu-rd) has pointed to you the right direction in his comment above on [delphi-coll](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-coll/).

The namespace **Collections.MultiMaps** provides a bunch of classes:

- TDistinctMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection.
- TDoubleSortedDistinctMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection.
- TDoubleSortedMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection.
- TMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection.
- TObjectDistinctMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection designed to store objects.
- TObjectDoubleSortedDistinctMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection designed to store objects.
- TObjectDoubleSortedMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection designed to store objects.
- TObjectMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection designed to store objects.
- TObjectSortedDistinctMultiMap: The generic distinct multi-map collection designed to store objects.
- TObjectSortedMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection designed to store objects.
- TSortedDistinctMultiMap: The generic distinct multi-map collection.
- TSortedMultiMap: The generic multi-map collection.

Comment: seems that the repository was changed to this place: https://github.com/ghquant/delphi-coll

Comment: a more up to date repo: https://github.com/delphidabbler/delphi-coll-xe

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sorted TStringList for your index. While it might be nice if your index were encapsulated into your main list object, that's no reason to let it stop you.

Create a new TStringList and have the Object pointer point to whatever you need.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if delphi supports multiple indexed lists... Maybe you can try with TMS TColumnListBox?

Comment: That sounds like a visual control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it doesn't just sound like it, it walks like it and it quacks like it, in fact, it simply is...